# Tkinter menu does not appear

Tags: tkinter, menu, rhel

I'm learning Tkinter using a tutorial and the menu isn't appearing. I've found a few other examples of this happening, but they all appear to be Mac or simple typos. Here's my minimum example:

```
from tkinter import *

# Create the root window
root = Tk()
root.title("DebugExample")

# Menu bar
menu_bar = Menu(root)
item = Menu(menu_bar)
item.add_command(label='New')
item.add_cascade(label='File', menu=item)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Task name label
lTaskName = Label(root, text = "Just some text to give content for the window")
lTaskName.grid()

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```

And the result:
[image: Generated Window]

I can see that there's an extra line below the title that's not there if I take out the menu code altogether so I thought perhaps it was a spacing thing, but I can't drag the line lower or otherwise expand it. I'm running Python 3.6.8 on RHEL 8.9 if that's helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following line

```py
item.add_cascade(label='File', menu=item)
```

should be changed to

```py
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=item)
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much more sense to me, but I don't know why it was the other way in the tutorial...

Comment: Not all tutorials on internet are good.  You need to understand what you learn.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnt show up because you are calling `add_cascade` on item.
its correct to call `add_cascade` to the menubar.
Heres corrected code:

```
from tkinter import *

# Create the root window
root = Tk()
root.title("DebugExample")

# Menu bar
menu_bar = Menu(root)
item = Menu(menu_bar)
item.add_command(label='New')
menu_bar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=item)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

# Task name label
lTaskName = Label(root, text = "Just some text to give content for the window")
lTaskName.grid()

# Run the main loop
root.mainloop()
```